# Необходимый стек технологий для Data Mining

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, sql-server, data-mining

Занимаюсь активным изучением направления Data Mining и в приложении к нему Python-ом (использую источники: coursera, открытое образование, книги - Доусон, Лутц и т.д.). Основы языка мне уже ясны. Решил для того чтобы как следует разобраться написать приложение для анализа большого объема данных с фондового рынка, как наиболее открытых и очищенных. В простом виде - на истории проблем не составило. Рабочий прототип на VBA тоже реализовал без проблем.

Но по мере усложнения задачи (увеличения объема информации и перехода на обработку поступающих данных в режиме онлайн) столкнулся с тем что не хватает знаний и непонятно в какую сторону копать. Надо изучать библиотеки. Вопрос на каких сосредоточиться (Nympy, matplotlib, pandas?)

Что нужно: Эффективно хранить и обрабатывать временные ряды данных, отрисовывать это все в виде графиков, отрисовывать результаты анализа в виде трех(более?)мерных графиков для поиска вершин, иметь какой-нибудь простецкий UI, принимать информацию от торговой программы (а-ля Quik), которая умеет отдавать данные только по DDE и ODBC (это для меня самая сложная задача сейчас), эффективно хранить полученные данные и результаты промежуточного анализа (сейчас это текстовые файлы - смотрю в сторону MS SQL Server Express).

Comment: Всё вами перечисленное - это не big data, это data mining.

Comment: Спасибо. Поправил

Comment: Слишком большой и общий вопрос.

Comment: ну и я на это времени не месяц потрать собираюсь. Я не жду ответа подробного развернутого ответа, а просто направление. Что-то вроде: отрисовывать графики: matplotlib, гуи строить - такая то библиотечка, данные перекидывать такой-то интерфейс и все. Не более.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Попробую ответить на некоторые из ваших вопросов.

- Загрузка, выгрузка, первичная обработка табличных данных, визуализация - [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/). Для чтения финансовых данных существует - [pandas_datareader](https://pydata.github.io/pandas-datareader/stable/).
- Для более сложных графиков может понадобиться [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/contents.html), [seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/index.html), [bokeh](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/gallery.html), [plotly](https://plot.ly/python/). С визуализацией четырех и более мерных графиков у вас наверняка возникнут трудности - ни одна из известных мне библиотек этого делать не умеет (это как проецировать 3D объект на прямую).
- хранение данных: тут есть важный момент - если этими данными будут активно пользоваться 3+ пользователей, то стоит задуматься об использовании БД, т.к. там изначально отлично продуманы механизмы совместного доступа к данным и необходимые блокировки при записи. Если для одного пользователя, то можно попробовать HDF5, Feather, Parquet, etc. Кстати Pandas замечательно справляется со всем вышеперечисленным. NOTE: хранить данные в текстовых файлах не стоит - это путь сплошных мучений и проблем. Выбирайте хранилище, которое позовляет хранить нужные вам типы данных нативно - без преобразования в/из текста.
- дальше можно (и стоит) развиваться в сторону машинного обучения и нейронных сетей - [sklearn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/documentation.html), [tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/), [keras](https://keras.io/), [theano](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/), etc.

Comment: Огромное спасибо!!! Все понял.

Answer (score 1):

Небольшое дополнение. Если вы взялись изучать Data Mining, то ни Доусон, ни Лутц, ни Любанович вам в этом не помогут.
Рекомендую обратить внимание на специализированные книги по теме Data Science с использованием Python. Для затравки:

1.Плас Дж.Вандер. Python для сложных задач: наука о данных и машинное обучение.

2.Луис Педро Коэльо, Вилли Ричарт.Как извлечь больше информации из данных
путем построения практичных систем машинного обучения на языке Python.

3.Уэс Маккинли. Python и анализ данных.

4.Андреас Мюллер, Сара Гвидо.Введение в машинное обучение с помощью Python.

5.Себастьян Рашка. Python и машинное обучение.

6.Силен Деви, Мейсман Арно, Али Мохамед. Основы Data Sсience и Big Data. Python и наука о данных.

Если есть английский, то список будет намного шире, но думаю, на начальном этапе и этого более чем хватит.
Удачи.

Comment: Большое спасибо за список книг! Эх, чувствую впереди у меня будет веселый и насыщенный год-полтора)))

Answer (score 0):

Возможно поможет:
По стеку NumPy, Pandas, Matplotlib и другим визуализациям очень хорошо помогает разобраться ресурс DataCamp.com

Я сейчас тоже активно изучаю это направление. По началу перебрал много всевозможных ресурсов и книг, но здесь более интересно и главное понятно объясняется и усваивается материал. И конечно же офиц. документация.

Из минусов: все как всегда платно и на английском.